# PHP link to profile page

Tags: php, mysql

Im new on php, so i need some sugests for following code:

```
<?php
// Start the session (pretty important!)
session_start();

// Establish a link to the database
$dbLink = mysql_connect('', '', '');
if (!$dbLink) die('Can\'t establish a connection to the database: ' . mysql_error());

$dbSelected = mysql_select_db('', $dbLink);
if (!$dbSelected) die ('We\'re connected, but can\'t use the table: ' . mysql_error());

$isUserLoggedIn = false;  
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE session_id = "' . session_id() . '" LIMIT 1';  
$userResult = mysql_query($query);  
if(mysql_num_rows($userResult) == 1) {  
    $_SESSION['user'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($userResult);  
    $isUserLoggedIn = true;  
} else {  
    if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) != 'conectare.php') {  
        header('Location: conectare.php');  
        exit;  
    }  
}  
?>
```

Upper code verify if user it's logged in or not..

I need to create a profil link, like following:

**http://site.com/profile.php?name=NAME-OF-USER**

Can someone give me a ideea?

Im newbie on php, so pls understand me..

PS: Please dont tell me to use mysql, pdo and another, i allready know the beneficts, i need only answers for my code..

Thank you !

Comment: you don't need the `exit;` at the end, `header(..)` already takes care of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is echo some html:

```
$username = "foo";
echo "<a href=\"http://site.com/profile.php?name=".$username." \">profile link</a>";
```

Note: I use `\"` to escape the `"`

More information about strings in php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: ty my friend. i will try that.. i'll come back with final answer if work

Comment: actualy works on curent profile.. but if i need to see another profile from another user, how can i proceed.. curent code, seems to not show the another profile of another users

Comment: You only have to change the variable `$username` to the user you want the profile of.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the string info I've included in my answer in order to figure these things out in the future.

Answer (score 2):

you simply need to use the get variable

create the link that will be clicked like this

the link that will be clicked on home page or any other page

```
 <?php
 $username='test';//the variable containing the username
 echo'<a href="mysite.com/profile.php?user='.$username.'">
      The link redirecting to profile page
      </a>';
 ?>
```

the address bar will turn something like this www.mysite.com/profile.php?user=test

then on the profile page

```
<?php
$username_selector=$_GET['user']//in this case the value got from the link clicked is test
//then just select the necessary data using the variable storing the value got from th link clicked
?>
```